# Auto-formatting tool for VBscript

Tags: vbscript, code-formatting

I'm looking for a light, free tool to format my Vbscript code.

The only way I've found so far is to auto-format it in VisualStudio. Although, it's too much to launch VisualStudio for this purpose.

Is there any web app or a free light tool for this purpose? Maybe a plugin for Notepad++?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried:

[VB Indent](http://www.vbindent.com/?indent) - paste your VBScript or VB code, press the button, and it'll indent for you.

or

[ASP Indent](http://www.aspindent.com/?indent) - auto formatting of your ASP Code. It will not format HTML, though. It's only checking and formatting the text between the `<% %>`

There don't appear to be any user settings, but it works!

Comment: These tools are dead now

Answer (score 4):

Use [VBScript Beautifier](http://www.daansystems.com/vbsbeaut/) freeware. It is an editor but has facility to auto indent for existing VB script. It may be useful. I have used it and it's fine with me for using with some old scripts which are written without indentation from some unknown developers without indents/comments!

Comment: VBScript Beautifier doesn't support `Class` keyword for me.

Answer (score 1):

[VBScript Beautifier](http://www.daansystems.com/vbsbeaut/) is commercial software.

["VB Indent"](http://www.vbindent.com/?indent) and ["ASP Indent"](http://www.aspindent.com/?indent) work, but they don't provide formatting options.

The Commercial VBScript Editor ["VBSEdit"](http://www.vbsedit.com/) has a code formatting option. This works most of the time. It only has problems with multiple commands in one line separated by `:`.

Answer (score 0):

VbsEdit worked for me.
From the menu select Edit->Reformat Code
https://www.vbsedit.com/