# Auto formatting classic ASP in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, autoformatting

Is it possible to auto format classic ASP code in VS2010?
Got a project with much old ASP code, written by a lot of different trainees, so it's ...   let's say complicated to read.
ASP is basic, VS supports basic, but it still doesn't want to format it with ctrl a+k+f.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a tool for your purpose: [ASP Indent](http://www.aspindent.com/?indent)

Source: [Auto-formatting tool for VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990221/auto-formatting-tool-for-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I've recently tried, was renaming the file from foobar.asp to foobar.asp.vb

Then running auto format over the file.

And renaming back to foobar.asp

It seems to fix the indents and Pascal cases all the reserved words. But just run a diff to make sure it didn't do anything weird in your specific files.