# How to color the whole row in a excel worksheet based on some condition using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to color the whole row based on some condition. I want to color only those rows in which there is a cell with comments "Please check manually". But when I apply the given code all the rows get colored. How do I correct it?

```
Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For oldRow = 1 To 28
    For newRow = 1 To 37
        If StrComp((Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oldRow, "J").Text), (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "J").Text), vbTextCompare) <> 0 And StrComp((Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oldRow, "L").Text), (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "O").Text), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            i = oldRow
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K") = "Please check manually"
            Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "I") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "I")
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "K")
            i = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next newRow
Next oldRow
```

Comment: You are placing the `"Please check manually"` in each cell if a `StrComp <> 0` so what is being put/compared in the `If StrComp` ? if this keeps evaluating `True` then you will get a colored `Row`

Comment: For cells with StrComp <> 0, "Please check manually" is placed but the red color background gets there for all the cells. I want red background to be there only for cells with StrComp<>0.

Comment: Do you know the specific `Column`? then it would be `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, "Column Here").Interior.Color = vbRed`

Comment: I want the whole row i.e. all the columns to get colored.

Comment: Your a bit confusing, you state only for cells with `StrComp<>0` and then whole row. Which is it? :-P

Comment: For the rows for which StrComp<>0 is True, I want the whole row i.e. all the horizontal cells for that 'i' to be colored.

Comment: Are you supposed to be checking the same row number in your compare on each pass? as your current loop goes: compare old row 1 to all new rows in turn, then go back and start old row 2 and compare it to all new rows. This indeed will make almost all of your rows highlight as you will get multiple <>0 for every inner loop you are processing

Answer (score -2):

You are exiting the FOR before you are exiting the IF, when the IF/ELSE should be nested inside the FOR loop.  I don't know how VB behaves when nested control statements do not match up, but I bet it's unpredictable behavior.

Also, it's much easier to catch these mistakes if you indent your code correctly.  There are [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990221/auto-formatting-tool-for-vbscript) for this, if you don't want to do it manually.

```
Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For oldRow = 1 To 28
    For newRow = 1 To 37
        If StrComp((Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oldRow, "J").Text), (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "J").Text), vbTextCompare) <> 0 
            And StrComp((Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(oldRow, "L").Text), (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "O").Text), vbTextCompare) <> 0 
        Then
            i = oldRow
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K") = "Please check manually"
            Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "I") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "I")
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newRow, "K")
            i = i + 1
    Exit For
    End If
    Next newRow
Next oldRow
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code in answers should be *answers*, as in rewritten, working snippets solving the problem at hand. For formatting issues in the original post, please use the "edit" feature to suggest a revision. If it significantly improves the readability of the original post, your edit will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As for your answer: I'm fairly certain VBA will handle that control flow without issues. I just tested it in a simplified way and the `Exit For` broke out of the inner loop as expected, without seeming to cause any issues with unclosed conditional statements. Remember that an `Exit For` and a `Next` statement are different - one is meant for breaking out of loops like this, while the other denotes the normal end of a loop body. If the control statements' bodies overlapped (instead of being nested), VBA would have thrown a compiler error.

Comment: "Exit For" should be removed then, since it is the last line anyway.  Code in my response was to demonstrate proper indentation.

Comment: The `Exit For` is still a critical part of the program's control flow. It serves to break out of the inner loop, preventing execution of some code. E.g. if the `Else` block is reached when `oldRow` is 12 and `newRow` is 25, then on the next iteration `oldRow` will be 13 and `newRow` will be 1. We're breaking out of the inner loop, incrementing in the outer loop, and restarting the inner loop from the start.

Comment: If you're more familiar with C-style languages, `Exit For` is like `break` and `Next` is like the end of a program block, e.g. `}`