# VB6 single line to multiline code

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

Here is the situation. I have been tasked with converting an old VB6 code to C#. The code I am converting make HEAVY usage of single line with multiple commands and it's getting really diffcult to follow. For exemple, a single line might contain nested If - Else with some For loop and Select Case all in the same line such as this:

```
If control0.Checked = True Then .Seek "=", control0.Tag Else If control1.Checked = True Then .Seek "=", control1.Tag Else If control2.Checked = True Then .Seek "=", control2.Tag Else For i = 0 To 10: Select Case controlMap(i).Checked: Case True: .Seek "=", controlMap(i).Tag: End Select: Next i
```

So my question is: Is there a tool that can convert those oneliners into properly formatted multilines?

Right now I can read the code using either NotePad++ or the VB6 IDE

Comment: Questions asking to recommend a tool are not programming questions and are generally closed. You might try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. That said, I have used https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=64016&lngWId=1 to good effect.

Comment: VB6 syntax is pretty similar to VB.NET or VBScript. Formatting tools for one of those may do what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990221/auto-formatting-tool-for-vbscript

Answer (score 2):

Use the VB Update Wizard (bundled with Visual Studio 2008) to convert it to VB.NET, after which it can be imported into a newer version of Visual Studio. It will be much easier to convert VB.NET into C#.

The Visual Studio 2013, 2015 and 2017 IDEs all support automatic formatting.

Comment: VB Update Wizard is not likely going to be a better route than the rewrite that the OP is suggesting.  I've never seen a VB6 project go in to the wizard and come out in any usable form.

Comment: Converting the project to vb.net (with vs 2008) is the first thing I tried to do months ago. But unfortunatly it failed. Than you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's easier to rewrite VB.NET into C# than VB6. And, the VB.NET code can be reformatted, even if the solution won't successfully compile. (For what it's worth, I will convert VB6 projects to VB.NET just so I can examine them in VS 2017.) Meanwhile, as for the projects the wizard generates, they tend to be 90%-plus complete, with some manual reworking required, but they will function once that reworking is done.

Comment: Back when I tried it I remember that the conversion process simply crashed without generating any code. But all this discussion would make for another SO Question. I up voted your suggested answer because I think it might be a good solution for some people. Unfortunatly it doesn't work in my particular case.

Comment: Thanks. If it crashed, you may have been missing an ActiveX or COM component.

Comment: I've used the upgrade wizard successfully (or at least effectively) numerous times. It is never perfect but in this situation it could well be used to at least resolve the ambiguities in the lines formatted as shown.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Notepad++ to do a find/replace on "Then" or "Else If" and replace it with "\nThen" and "\nElse If".  Do the same for "End If" and any other single-line things you wish to break apart.

Comment: You may need to turn on extended search mode in the find/replace box to use the escaped newline char "\n" in your replace action.

Comment: I just tried it. This almost does it but I notice that Notepad++ makes the indentation all wrong. This could lead to some error where one might think the next line after the "Then" is also part of the "If" statement .

Comment: Sounds like if it's a soft return it would keep the indentation perhaps.  Maybe one of the other chars in the extended set (other than '\n' would do that).

Comment: @Maxter, try an "\r" instead of "\n".  If that does not do it, I'd step thru them one at a time, do the replace, and then indent it where you want it.  It'll still be a whole lot faster than not doing it at all, and you'll know exactly where things should be lined up.

Comment: Didn't work either with \r. I will keep your suggestion in mind about doing it one at a time if nothing betther come up here. Thank you.

Comment: You need to switch 'Search Mode' to 'Extended' for the newlines to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to Luke G.'s answer, you can do a search and replace for the colon character (`:`) as well, replacing it with a new line. That's the character that VB uses to separate individual code statements that are on a single line.